# processes that cause heat loss in buildings

Tags: thermodynamics, building-physics

I'm looking for a fair study in which they assessed the importance of different processes that cause overall heat loss **in buildings**. With processes i mean convection, radiation, conduction trough the ground, wind driven ventilation, buoyancy-driven ventilation and infiltration.

I know that it depends on the building, climate..., but there should be some guidelines: which processes are important and which can be neglected in a realistic setting.

**Edit**

To make things more clear, I'm looking for a study that would **for instance** say:

Heat loss is due to:

- convection 40-60%
- radiation 10-25%
- buoyancy-driven ventilation 5-15%
- conduction through the ground <5%
- wind driven ventilation <1%

In case of such **imaginary** result, i would then neglect the influence of ground temperature and wind speed in my theoretical model.

Comment: It depends on the building... not sure why you expect physics to give you a different answer to what you already know from engineering?

Comment: I kinda doubt such a table exists, as there is large variations in building design.